# Definition of "loaf" in terms of a street suffix

Tags: meaning

The USPS has a [list of street suffixes](http://pe.usps.gov/text/pub28/28apc_002.htm) (like Street, Avenue, road, etc.) and acceptable abbreviations for them (like ST, AV, and RD)
One of them is **Loaf (LF)**. I've done a bit of research and cannot find a definition of loaf that makes sense in the context of a street suffix.

We have the common definitions of the noun (bread) and verb (to lounge around), and a region-specific (UK) one where loaf=head/brain, ie, loaf of bread (rhymes with head) that I found on Wiktionary.

(https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loaf)

**So what is a loaf in terms of a street name suffix?**

Comment: It's not familiar.  It's vaguely possible that the word is used for "block" in some cities somewhere.

Comment: [Use yer loaf, mate!](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22use+yer+loaf%22) *Obscure???!!!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers obscure here in the states. I've corrected that :)

Comment: Great question!

Comment: There's a tiny street in my neighborhood with that abbeviation PT.  It probably stands for Point, although there's nothing pointy about it.

Comment: @chiliNUT: I stand corrected. If I'd been asked to explain *why* "loaf" means "head", I'd have realised I'm just a parochial [berk.](http://www.cockneyrhymingslang.co.uk/slang/berkshire_hunt) But in the final analysis, the "meaning" of **loaf / lf** is so far removed from "use of English" that even though I don't yet know which reason I'm going to select, I can be quite unequivocal that I'm *definitely* going to closevote.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about "use of English"

Comment: @Oldcat: As it happens, I personally wrote the code that's probably used more than anything else in the UK in this particular area. I (was) retired several years ago, but I can assure you that the relevant lookup routine definitely included ***point -> pt***. If it occurred more than once, and seemed "accessible", I included it (but that particular one was well-known to everyone in bus company scheduling offices, so there was no chance of it being missed).

Comment: @chiliNUT: If you think the abbreviation **lf -> loaf** would be recognised by the average (or even "highly articulate") Anglophone, all I can say is perhaps we are "separated by a common language" more than myself and my American cousins! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I had deleted the comment you replied to because I wasnt sure if you were kidding around. The fact that it is clearly not recognized by the average Anglophone is why I asked the question in the first place

Comment: @chiliNUT: Sure - I was being a bit facetious. But the fact that (as I write) 11 people have been moved to upvote both the question *and* the answer here just goes to show how pointless it is for people like me to try to maintain some level of "focus" on this site. Actual questions about "use of ***English***" on this site don't usually attract that much attention.

Comment: @FumbleFingers English usage: "...refers to the conventional ways in which words or phrases are used, spoken, or written in a speech community...". If your argument is that it is not conventional, my reply would be that in a region with lots of "Lf streets" it would be easily recognizable, just as someone outside the UK might not recognize "loaf" as "head", or someone outside of Tuscon, Arizona would not be familiar with the word "Stravenue," words with common usage within their own distinct "speech communities"

Comment: @chiliNUT: My argument would be that ***loaf = head*** can be meaningfully described as "use of English", because *tens of millions* of people all over the world use it on a daily basis. I'd be surprised if more than a few thousand people (in a few specific regions) have any reason to connect ***lf*** and ***loaf***. It's not a matter of English usage as such - it's just a parochial abbreviation that would be meaningless just a few miles up the road.

Comment: @FumbleFingers the question wasnt asking for a definition of lf, it was asking for a definition of loaf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Notice that the list of street suffixes you gave also includes words like "mountain", "valley", "stream", "glen", and other nature words.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_Loaf_(Winona,_Minnesota)), there are a few hills and mountains in the US called ***Sugar Loaf***:

> The name "Sugar Loaf" refers to the former formation's resemblance to
>   the conical loaves that sugar used to be packaged and sold in. There
>   are many hills and mountains named "Sugar Loaf" in the United States.
>   At least three other hills or bluffs bearing the name "Sugar Loaf" are
>   located in or near the Mississippi River Valley

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugarloaf) is a photo of a classic sugarloaf.

Apparently, the word ***sugarloaf*** is "now used chiefly in similes and metaphors to describe the shape of other objects" ([here](https://www.google.com/#q=define+sugarloaf)).

In fact, there is a conventional use of ***sugarloaf*** which refers only to specific landforms (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugarloaf_(mountain))).

All of this points to the fact that the abbreviation ***LF*** can plausibly be taken to stand for ***loaf*** in constructions abbreviating "Sugar Loaf", as in

> - "I'm from Sugar LF."
> - "I live on Sugar LF."

That this is correct is corroborated by [this](http://www.whereorg.com/matterhorn-nursery-at-sugar-lf-11845728) website, where "LF" is used to abbreviate the "loaf" in "Sugar Loaf."

In fact, if you [google](https://www.google.com/#q=sugar+lf%2C+address) "Sugar LF, address", you get a lot of hits for streets/places apparently called "Sugar Loaf."

One can (presumably) also use "LF" to abbreviate "loaf" in place names like "High Loaf" and "White Loaf", although I can find no addresses corroborating this.

Comment: ha! and you found some real street addresses to back it up. awesome

Comment: I think you've got it. One of the OED's obsolete definitions of *loaf* is *a mass or lump* whence *meatloaf* and places like [High Loaf](http://geonames.usgs.gov/apex/f?p=136:3:35126289060779::NO::P3_FID,P3_TITLE:1020747,High%20Loaf%20Mountain), [Brown Loaf](http://geonames.usgs.gov/apex/f?p=136:3:35126289060779::NO::P3_FID,P3_TITLE:611097,Brown%20Loaf). [Twopenny Loaf](http://geonames.usgs.gov/apex/f?p=136:3:35126289060779::NO::P3_FID,P3_TITLE:615443,Twopenny%20Loaf), [White Loaf](http://geonames.usgs.gov/apex/f?p=136:3:35126289060779::NO::P3_FID,P3_TITLE:608823,Whiteloaf%20Mountain), etc.

Comment: @choster, It would be interesting to know whether the abbreviation "LF" was derived directly from "Sugar Loaf" or whether it was derived more generally from names like those in your list. Given the amount of places designated "Sugar Loaf" in contrast to other places designated with "loaf", it seems likely the former.

Comment: Nice bit of detective work there!

Comment: The USPS list is truly mind-boggling.  It lists HL (Hill), MTN (Mountain), BLF (Bluff) and - worthy of its own question - STR for "STREME" (sic).